# WPF User Control inside tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have three tabs in my window and one of them contains   a user control
that connected to camera logic and there is problem with that
because every time that i switch between the tabs and go out from the camera tab the user control is unloaded and when i return to the camera tab the user control is loaded again, so is there any way to prevent the unloading of the user control when switching between tabs?

Comment: Maybe don't change tabs?  [mcve]

Comment: If your camera connection logic relies on the view state, then the connection should only exist for the sake for viewing. Otherwise, decouple the camera connection from the view.